# Calling RenderAction and Partial from class Inheriting from WebViewPage<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, render

I have MVC 5 project where I have a bunch of views, and I've set it in the web.config in the folder to have them all inherit from a custom class which inherits from WebViewPage so that I can add in properties/methods that all views can use.

```
public abstract class SCView<T> : WebViewPage<T> 
{


}
```

I happen to have a little bit of presentation logic (yes, I know, not good - but I have to do this, for a lot of different reasons). The logic is simple enough, and goes as follows:

```
if([condition])
            {
                Html.RenderAction("DoThis", "Page", new { Area = "Common", model = Model, viewname = "TitlePanel" });
            }
            else if([another condition])
            {
                Html.Partial("/Areas/Common/Views/Media/TitlePanelEdit.cshtml", Model) *@
            }
```

Essentially, if the first condition is met, I need to display a certain controller action - else, render a different partial view.

I would like to not do this in every view - so I was hoping to incorporate this logic in the CustomView class somehow. However, I'm finding that the Html helper methods cannot be used directly in this class - if I was inside a controller, this would be easier, obviously. Is there anyway I can put this so that this logic can be centralized?

Comment: What prevents you from using the Html Helper methods?  Aren't most of those just ordinary static methods?

Comment: The same way you use any other `static` method: `Html.StaticMethodName(someParameters)`.  Is your problem simply that you're not including the proper namespace?

Comment: Let me clarify - my real issue is that the helper methods usually return Htmlstring or MvcHtmlString - in this case, Html.RenderAction is void, whilst Html.Partial returns a view.... how can I encompass that whole logic in the view base?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something in your question, however, it seems to me that you just need to standardise your calls.

either pick

```
    @Html.Action
    @Html.Partial
```

Or

```
    @Html.RenderAction
    @Html.RenderPartial
```

Rather than mixing the types, then your viewbase logic will be able to return the same type, either void in the case of Render... as those output to the stream, or an mvchtmlstring if you go with the non render versions